# Alexa Skill working on amazon.developer console test but not working in beta-testing for alexa App

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, beta

I am currently in development mode for the skill. It is using Lambda endpoint. The skill is working in https://developer.amazon.com/alexa/console/ask/test/

When I sent invites for Beta testing and followed the Beta testing instructions on a different (email account with Alexa), the application is giving “Unexpected communication issue: There was a problem communicating with the requested skill” 
Request identifier: amzn1.echo-api.request.[some-id]

I am not getting any logs in CloudWatch for my Lambda function

[Update] More info: 
The skill is available in all countries and regions where Amazon distributes skills.

This is a dummy skill, with only one intent, triggered by a command like this `Alexa open mySkill and tell me a new fact`, after which the control passes on to Lambda function which selects a fact string randomly from an array.

Comment: Could you add a little context to the problem? It will be very hard to get to the issue with out some more information. Does the skill pull from a data source that is perhaps only local to you, is it using account linking that only you have enabled are the testers in a region that the skill is setup to respond in? Please some more info.

Comment: How are the beta testers testing your skill?, are they using an Echo device?

Comment: @CicilThomas I am trying beta testing with my phone (using Alexa app) as well as Echo dot device. Both give the same error.

Comment: @ChuckLaPress updated the problem statement with more information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it finally. The problem was mainly due to 2 reasons:

1. I had created multiple skills (for testing) and didn't noticed that
   they had similar invocation words (silly me :/ ). One of them was
   pointing to an older AWS account. Thanks @ChuckLaPress for the hint.
2. Language settings. I had used the default en-US language and was trying from India. Solved it by including support for all other english languages. Details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51881028/4970598).