# custom skill with https endpoint is not reachable from alexa app. It returns "Sorry, i don't know about that " or "Sorry, i am not sure"

Tags: php, alexa-voice-service, alexa-skills-kit

I have written skill endpoints in PHP which returns proper response in test simulator But not reachable from alexa app. My custom skill is enabled in alexa app which is shown under skill & games -> development --> myskill.

How to identify the issue what exactly it is returning ? and How to test custom skills on alexa app ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I don't have enough reputation points to post this as a comment, though I feel it might be more that than an answer.)

Check that the Alexa App is running the same version of the language (for example [English UK, English US, English IN](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/develop-skills-in-multiple-languages.html), etc.) as the test simulator.

I had this problem a while back - had used English US for my skill, so I got the “Sorry, I am not sure” response until I added an English UK version.

Have a look here as well for a previous similar question: [Alexa Skill not recognized when tested on Echo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39068523/alexa-skill-not-recognized-when-tested-on-echo).

Comment: Is Alexa enabled device required for testing skills ? or Can we test skills directly on alexa app without using any device ?  like alexa dot, alexa echo etc.

Comment: You can test in the Alexa app without having a physical Alexa-enabled device. There are however [some limitations](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/devconsole/test-your-skill.html) to what the simulator and Alexa app can do.